# C++17 inline static map error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++17

I have something similar to this:

```
//file1.h
class Base {

private:
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::string>> table;
}
```

And to make everything work as expect I write this:

```
//file1.cpp
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::string>> Base::table = {
    {
      1, std::unordered_map<int, std::string> { 
           {12, "asset:12/"},
           {-3, "asset:24/"},
           //...
         }
    },
     //...
};
```

---

I use visual studio 2017 latest update (15.8.5) and this code fails:

```
//file1.h
class Base {

private:
    inline static std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::string>> table = {
        {
          1, std::unordered_map<int, std::string> { 
               {12, "asset:12/"},
               {-3, "asset:24/"},
               //...
             }
        },
         //...
    };
```

Why does this inline declaration fail? I have seen that since `C++17` you can have inline static declarations. The problem is in the list header and it states:

```
**_Pnode** was 0xDDDDDDDD.
```

Is it a problem with maps? I have run the code in coliru and I didn't have the issue that I've found in VS. Screen:

[image]

The output dialog is:

> The thread 0x3790 has exited with code 0 (0x0). Exception thrown: read
>   access violation.
>   **_Pnode** was 0xDDDDDDDD.

Exit code is 0 but I don't understand where the access violation could happen.

Comment: 0xDDDDDDDD : Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging heap to mark freed heap memory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations

Comment: See my updated question @drescherjm!

Comment: is that all code you have? It really possible that MS got defects in implementation. coliru uses some unnamed build of g++, it's not fully compatible with cl... if you want particular version of GCC or clang, use wandbox or similar, they allow to choose and report which build they use.

Comment: There are too many open possibilities here, not the least of which is bug elsewhere being exposed here. Could we trouble you for an [mcve]?

Comment: you free'd something then tried to use it. Most likely, you are in UB land and one implementation seemed to work and in the MS one the debug heap forced a clearer behavior

Comment: I am voting to close because the code you show works for me on VS15.9.5.